# Function wrapper invocation in Polymer script block

Tags: polymer-1.0

I have seen some polymer elements (e.g. paper-menu, paper-dialog) in their script block starts with anonymous function wrapper like this -

```
<script>
(function() {

  Polymer({

    is: 'paper-menu',

    behaviors: [
       Polymer.IronMenuBehavior
    ]

  });

})();
</script>
```

I understand anonymous function wrapper for creating its closure. But what is the implication for polymer element. Why paper-menu needs to create its own closure while some elements do not? Anyone can explain this?